# SQLite close() was never explicitly called on database in android

Tags: android

i am trying to fetch contacts using content provider and save them in sqlite database.I am properly closing cursor then database in finally block but still facing this problem please suggest how to solve it.

Comment: you should close db too after getting all contact and use async task to save record in sqlite from contact..

Comment: @Nirmal i am closing d also in finally block

Comment: @ManishSrivastava this is the same i am doing for that

Comment: can you paste your code here? I am using same code no issue..
see here-http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/06/get-phone-contacts-details-in-android_6.html

Comment: It might be open at some where.so please check it once.

Comment: @ManishSrivastava i will use pastie

Comment: @ManishSrivastava look at here http://pastie.org/8217584

Comment: As you can see that link is not working try others..

Comment: @ManishSrivastava which link

Comment: I have given you one and for others do google..